# Printing url with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, session, wkhtmltopdf

My problem is that I need to print an url with wkhtmltopdf, but the url to print starts like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header('Location:../../../index.php');
}
```

That means that the user has to be authenticated, but from wkhtmltopdf the file generated prints the index.php and never the content of imprimir_ingreso.php.

This is my code source until now:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header("Location:../../index.php");
}

$sesion_id= session_id();
system("C://\"Program Files\"//wkhtmltopdf//bin//wkhtmltopdf --cookie 'sessionid' $sesion_id http://localhost/proyecto/hc/php/admisiones/ambulatorio/imprimir_ingreso.php?id_ingreso=84 hc.pdf");
```

I don't know what exactly this is doing **--cookie 'sessionid' $sesion_id**, because the url to print starts with this **!isset($_SESSION['login'])** to redirect to index.php with an unauthenticated user.

Comment: i would edit `imprimir_ingreso.php` to bypass authentication for wkhtmltopdf

Comment: But I can delete the  !isset($_SESSION['login']), otherwise anyone could see the content of that url.I don't find the way to solve it.